# How can I put inside a curator project a suggester field (ElasticSearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator, elasticsearch-suggester

My question is simple, I only want to know how can I add a field "suggester" correctly inside a curator project, because the next configuration not adds the field:

```
5:
action: create_index
description: "Create new index for recipes"
options:
  name: '<active-recipes-{now+1d{yyyyMMdd}}>'
  continue_if_exception: True
  extra_settings:
    mappings:
      properties:
        ...
        suggest:
          type: completion,
          analyzer: simple,
          search_analyzer: simple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is delete the commas, I learned because this break production, so not put any commas in curator...

```
5:
action: create_index
description: "Create new index for recipes"
options:
  name: '<active-recipes-{now+1d{yyyyMMdd}}>'
  continue_if_exception: True
  extra_settings:
    mappings:
      properties:
        ...
        suggest:
          type: completion
          analyzer: simple
          search_analyzer: simple
```